# How to limit value of fontsizeinput in Tinymce?

Tags: tinymce

I'm using Tinymce v6.x, there is an option "fontsizeinput" to set fontsize of a block. Now i want to limit font size at 12px - 20px, and wondering where to set it while using fontsizeinput option

is there any options to set range of fontsizeinput?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.